# Optimal option to use 9 V battery to power 5 V ATtiny85

Tags: voltage-regulator, attiny85

I am designing a remote sensor which is based on an ATtiny85 chip and a RF433 module.

To increase range, I need to supply 9 V (500 mAh) to the RF433 module, however, the ATtiny85 is only 3.3 to 5 V. (My sensor minimum voltage is 3.3 V.)

The ATtiny85 plus soil moisture sensors requires only around 7 mA for 2 seconds in active state and it'll consume 0.005 mA while sleeping for 30 minutes.

I don't know which voltage regulators to choose, or just a simple voltage divider. My requirement is long battery life (1 to 2 years).

Comment: It will be active 2 seconds, is that every minute, day, month, etc? A 9V battery will give you about +- 500 mAh. You might reconsider your power source and your choice of components. A linear regulator will probably drain the battery in a relative short time depending on which one you chose.

Comment: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22008E.pdf

Comment: might be worth considering solar power instead.

Comment: PS: 30 minute sleep and around 500mah battery.